# Error while accessing the Oauth of scribe code

Tags: oauth-2.0

Fetching the Request Token...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import org.apache cannot be resolved
    Base64 cannot be resolved

```
at org.scribe.services.HMACSha1SignatureService.<init>(HMACSha1SignatureService.java:6)
at org.scribe.builder.api.DefaultApi10a.getSignatureService(DefaultApi10a.java:73)
at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.addOAuthParams(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:60)
at org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl.getRequestToken(OAuth10aServiceImpl.java:43)
at org.scribe.examples.DiggExample2.main(DiggExample2.java:36)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need apache commons-codec jar. I could see it from project's POM file dependency list.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```